# Get SharePoint credentials from SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, credentials, savefiledialog

I'm creating a client application where the user will be able to open a Windows Forms SaveFileDialog. There the user will enter a specific SharePoint library. Thankfully for me, the saveFileDialog prompts for credentials every time the user enters to a library where he doesn't have access. Later I need to call some SharePoint web services. However I need the credentials the user entered to call them. Do you know how can I get those credentials?
If that helps I could use a native saveFileDialog instead of Windows Forms one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is an internal application, you can pass the user credentials of the current user to the web service.

[Getting NetworkCredential for current user (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949340/getting-networkcredential-for-current-user-c)