# Getting Credentials for LogonAs in Business Connector

Tags: axapta, credentials, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

I'm calling an AX (2009) method from within a .Net component embedded in a form and need to Logon in order to do so. For security purposes I need to use LogonAs rather than the Logon method.

Is there any way of automatically retrieving the credentials of the machine the component will be installed on (perhaps from a config file?)? I've hard coded these details for testing on my machine, but this is hardly the way to go when deploying the solution.

In summary, where can I get the machine credentials needed to call the LogonAs method for interfacing with AX (via Business Connector)?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with other tools designed for AX that utilize the business connector, they always prompt the user for credentials within the UI, and use those credentials to connect.

Also, since you need a NetworkCredential object to use the LogonAs method of the BC, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949340/getting-networkcredential-for-current-user-c) to see if maybe it can help with a little more context.