# How to get the current user credential?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a NetworkCredential based on the logged in user like:

```
var cred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

Usually the code is running on a system which the user is logged in using his/her password. So I don't want to get the password again. My question has 2 parts:

**Question 1.** Is there a way to get the current Credential for Desktop applications? Something like:

```
var cred = NetworkCredential.Current;
```

**Question 2.** In a web SPA application, how can I pass the credential to the server via WebApi so I can do the work using his/her credential?

Comment: username and password are stored in database?

Comment: @KrunalPatil No, the scenario is this: Users Logged in using his/her username and password, and then runs the desktop application or navigates to a web page. I want to use the existing credential without asking username and password from the user redundantly.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949340/982431) out to answer your first question.

Comment: @HuorSwords Thanks, that helps for the first part. Any idea about the second question?

Comment: Perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12675503/982431) show you the way...